# Table click function called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am performing some operation on the event of any `td` cell click in the table 
I call the below function:

```
$('#tablename').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    var column = delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex],
        row = this.parentNode.cells[1];

    if ($(row).text().trim() == "") {
        row = this.parentNode.cells[0];
    }
    var rowvalue = $(row).text();
    var columnvalue = $(column).text();
    alert(rowvalue, columnvalue);
})
```

The function gets called twice. What ever operation I perform inside the function is being done twice. Can you please advise.
The alert comes twice

Comment: Post all the relevant code for us to be able to help!

Comment: Often this is caused be registering to the event more than once.

Comment: do you have nested tables? tables inside <td>'s?

Comment: You should post more details. Where is the code you posted defined? Maybe this listener is defined twice.

Comment: Nope  i dont have nested tables

Comment: Listener in the sense? I do have one table with some data in it. I want to retrieve the corresponding column header and row header on a cell click .

Comment: please check that if you have called my_script.js and my_script.min.js in same file

Comment: Can you post your html code too?

Comment: @NirmalAnand - your code is most certainly **not** enough. please provide a link to see this live. Since there is nothing wrong with the function, the fault must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('#tablename').off('click','td').on('click', 'td', function(e){
}
I Changed the function like this and it worked